# Matrix with eigenvalues no negatives: What is $\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{tA}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Here's a homework question I've been stuck on for a while. My question is what can you tell about $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{tA}$$ if $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix and you know that every eigenvalue of $A$ has negative real part?. I think it's zero, but I don't know how to prove it!!

Thanks!

Comment: How does one interpret a number raised to a matrix power? I've never heard of this before...

Comment: You say in the title, "eigenvalues no negatives" and in the question "every eigenvalue of $A$ has negative real part?" Which is it?

Comment: Sorry I wrote "eigenvalues no negatives" in short, but is actually  "every eigenvalue of A has negative real part?" and for the first question $$e^{tA}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(tA)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: That should be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$.

Comment: Is $A$ diagonalizable?

Comment: Not necessary!!  but you can write it in a Canonical Jordan Form

Comment: @TomBuilder: I have a bit of problem with the nilpotent part of JCF for the limit: consider the matrix $[-1,1;0,-1]$.

Comment: What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: if $\text{Re}(\lambda) < 0$, $$\lim_{t \to +\infty} e^{t\lambda} = 0$$

Hint 2: if $A = S D S^{-1}$, $e^{tA} = S e^{tD} S^{-1}$.

Alternatively, if you like complex variables, 
$$e^{tA} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma e^{tz} (zI - A)^{-1} \; dz $$

where $\Gamma$ is a simple positively oriented closed contour enclosing the eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh I think I got it!! $e^{tD}$ results to be a diagonal matrix with entries $e^{\lambda_i}$ right?

Comment: Yes, if $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think, I used the Jordan canonical form, but I don't know how to treat the blocks from imaginary eigenvalues.

Comment: @TomBuilder, do you know how to find $e^{tJ}$ if $J$ is in Jordan Form?

Comment: Yes @WillJagy all entries are in the form $P(x)e^{at}Sen(bt)$ or $P(t)e^{at}Cos(bt)$, where $\lambda=a+ib$. I think that solves everithing.

Comment: An $n \times n$ Jordan block is of the form $B = \lambda I + N$, where $N^n = 0$.  Then $$e^{tB} = e^{t\lambda} e^N = e^{t\lambda} \left(I + \dfrac{N}{1!} + \dfrac{N^2}{2!} + \ldots + \dfrac{N^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael: If $B=\lambda I+N$ then $tB=\lambda tI+tN$, and so $e^{tB}=e^t\lambda\cdot e^{tN}$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot some $t$'s: $$e^{t\lambda} e^{tN} = e^{t\lambda} \left(I + t \dfrac{N}{1!} + t^2 \dfrac{N^2}{2!} + \ldots + t^{n-1} \dfrac{N^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)$$